# TwitterOAuth error:140770FC:SSL

Tags: api, ssl, twitter

I started to work with twitter API and I'm using TwitterOAuth library but when I run it I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message 'error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol' in C:\wamp\www\tweeterapp\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 400
```

and my code is :

```
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth/autoload.php");
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$twitteruser = "blah";
$notweets = 30;
$consumerkey = "blah";
$consumersecret = "blah";
$accesstoken = "blah-blah";
$accesstokensecret = "blah";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$content = $connection->get("statuses/home_timeline", array("count" => 25,"exclude_replies" => true));
echo json_encode($content);
```